# ObjectiveC Syntax for Specifying Protocol Name in Method Argument

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

What's the ObjectiveC syntax for specifying a protocol as an argument in a method?

Say I have 2 protocols, MyProtocol and MyProtocolCB:

```
@protocol MyProtocolCB <NSObject>
- (void) func;
@end

@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>
- (void) register:(MyProtocolCB*) cb;
@end
```

I'm receiving this syntax error:
`error: expected type-specifier before 'MyProtocolCB'`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Try:

```
- (void) register:(NSObject<MyProtocol>*) cb;
```

Comment: You also might use more generic `id<MyProtocol>` instead of `NSObject<MyProtocol>*`, especially if `MyProtocol` already extends `NSObject` protocol

Comment: @iPhone beginner: it's not exactly the same. some methods in the NSObject class are not in the NSObject protocol

Answer (score 0):

use `id` instead of `NSObject` as you already know `id` is the `instance` type or generic type so if you use id it will help you in big perspective.

```
- (void) register:(id<MyProtocol>*) sender;
```